# Parsing json with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm pretty confused and every way I've tried I keep getting internal error 500.

I'm trying to parse [THIS json](http://steamcommunity.com/id/koraktor/inventory/json/730/2/) using PHP and return it to the client side.

inventory.php

```
/**
* Fetches users inventory. 
*/
$userId = $_GET['userId'];
$inventoryUrl = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/' . $userId . '/inventory/json/730/2/';

if ($userId) {
    $url = file_get_contents($inventoryUrl);
    $json = json_decode($url);
    print_r($json);
}
```

And with jQuery I'm trying to fetch that object and parse it so I can insert it into html.

```
$.when(getUserInventory('koraktor')).done(function(data){
    var inventory = data;
    var selectItemsElem = $('#select-items');
    console.log(inventory);

    //console.log(inventory);
});


function getUserInventory(userId) {
    var inventoryUrl = 'inventory.php';
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'inventory.php',
        data: {userId: userId},
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        return data;
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });

}

});
```

In console it shows:

[image]

I need to parse $object->rgInventory->rgDescriptions

I'm just not sure how though.

SO my question is, how do I correctly parse this object so I can use a `for loop` and how would I use the for loop so I can insert each item into html?

Comment: `json_decode($json, true)` to convert into array instead of stdClass.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the properties of the `rgInventory` part of your object. These are your items.

```
for(var item in inventory.rgInventory) {

   if (inventory.rgInventory.hasOwnPrioperty(item) )
      console.log(item.id)

}
```